# How to access components from different file controller?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Suppose I have two FXML files: main and the one with the custom component. I want access to the main file components from the custom controller, like this:

Main.fxml:

```
<FlowPane>
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="source" />
        <CustomBox fx:id="cbox" />
    </children>
</FlowPane>
```

Custom.fxml:

```
<fx:root type="HBox">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="showButton" onAction="#show" text="Show" />
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

CustomBox.java:

```
public class CustomBox extends HBox {
    @FXML
    private TextField source;

    public CustomBox() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Custom.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    protected void show() {
        System.out.println(source.getText());
    }
}
```

But the method show() gives me NPE. How can I bind components and controllers from different files?

Comment: You can't inject controls defined in one FXML file into the controller for another FXML file - and in general it is bad practice to expose controls outside of the controller for the FXML in which they are defined. Instead, pass a reference to the main controller to the custom component, and call a method on the main controller to retrieve the text (or use a MVC approach and define a model class, and share an instance of the model with both controllers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a controller for the main FXML file, and expose the text from it:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextField source ;

    @FXML
    private CustomBox cbox ;

    public String getText() {
        return source.getText();
    }

    @FXML
    protected void initialize() {
        cbox.setMainController(this);
    }
}
```

and of course specify it as the controller class in the `Main.fxml` file

```xml
<FlowPane fx:controller="my.package.MainController">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="source" />
        <CustomBox fx:id="cbox" />
    </children>
</FlowPane>
```

Then modify your `CustomBox` as

```
public class CustomBox extends HBox {

    private MainController mainController ;

    public CustomBox() {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Custom.fxml"));
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController ;
    }

    public MainController getMainController() {
        return mainController ;
    }

    @FXML
    protected void show() {
        System.out.println(mainController.getText());
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this, but you might just be able to specify the main controller in the FXML file:

```xml
<FlowPane fx:controller="my.package.MainController">
    <children>
        <TextField fx:id="source" />
        <CustomBox fx:id="cbox" mainController="$controller" />
    </children>
</FlowPane>
```

and then omit the `initialize()` method in the `MainController`:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextField source ;

    public String getText() {
        return source.getText();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get the idea.